# Дрон и скутер — значения

Tags: этимология, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Сейчас скутером называют мотоцикл (или мотороллер?), а дроном — беспилотный летающий аппарат.
Когда и как появились эти значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба слова в таком значении - совсем недавние.
Появление первого (мотоцикла) я зафиксировал лет пять назад, при этом оно относилось только к одному из типов мотороллера - гоночному. Сейчас уже практически любой мотоцикл величают скутером. Ранее слово относилось только к водному "мотоциклу". Противопоставлялось глиссеру. Причину такого перехода назвать трудно, видимо дело в том, что у нас почти не знакомы с гидроциклами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего подобного в отношении скутера-мотоцикла в СССР я не помню.

Дрон - вообще слово совсем недавнее, ранее встречалось только как личное имя. Однако в данном случае его появление вполне мотивировано отсутствием удобного синонима. Можно ожидать, что оно станет общелитературным.

(+)
Да, оба слова исходно из английского, но учитывая изменение значения без дополнительных оговорок, это утверждение нельзя считать полностью корректным.
Самое главное - в английском гидроцикл скутером никогда не назывался.

Answer (score 1):

*Скутером* (английское чтение слова для исконно *итальянского* средства передвижения scooter) сейчас называют подзабытый и всемирно популярный в 60-х годах прошлого века **мотороллер** (разновидность городского мотоцикла с уменьшенными колёсами и с элементами комфорта; сейчас слово распространилось и на упрощённые, дешевые конструкции типа мопеда). Раньше в русском скутером называли разновидность малого скоростного *катера*.

*Дронами* (англ. drone) всё чаще называют **беспилотники**, хотя последнее слово употреблялось *всегда*. Возможно, это связано и с необходимостью в отдельном названии для малых аппаратов, доступных в быту.

Само явление употребления новых слов вместо имеющихся отчасти связано со случайными заимствованиями из английских текстов и массовостью дилетантских переводов от тележурналистов. Белок в таких переводах становится "*протеином*", все спортсмены - "*атлетами*", рирпроекция - "*хромакеем*" и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Появились с английского языка.

Беспилотный летательный аппарат (БПЛА, реже БЛА; в разговорной речи также «беспилотник» или «**дрон**», от англ. ***drone*** — **трутень**) — летательный аппарат без экипажа на борту.

Скутер — альтернативное название мотороллера.

Скутер — альтернативное название гидроцикла.

Скутер — разновидность подводного буксировщика.

**Скутер** (англ. ***scooter*** «самокат» от ***scoot*** — **удирать**).

Comment: Появились с английского языка... Переведите, пожалуйста!

Comment: @shampar Что именно перевести?

Comment: Как говорится, с русского на русский. В школе говорят: «То же, но другими словами».

Comment: @shampar А что же здесь непонятного? Вопрос: *Когда и как появились эти значения?* Начало ответа: *Появились с английского языка.*

Comment: «С потолка в одночасье» появится может, ну ещё пару примеров припомнить смогу, не очень приличных, к сожалению. И это всё.

Comment: "С потолка" слово появит**ь**ся не может. Это равносильно "от фонаря". Что же такого плохого, что слова появились с английского?

Comment: Встретите такое в НК и Гугле, поговорим. «С языка» можно перевести и только.

Comment: Сразу бы сказали, что стилистика не нравится. "Появилось с английского" -  2490 результатов. Фраза разговорная. Ещё примеры: *Много людей **появилось с** той стороны. **Появилось с** северного направления. **Появилось с** моря. **Появилось c версии.** [В русском языке **появилось из** английского.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Популярность)*

Answer (score 0):

Дрон (в английском словаре)
1. сущ. 
1) а) трутень (в пчелином улье) б) перен. трутень, тунеядец 
2) гудение, гул, жужжание, шум Syn : hum, buzz 
3) а) басовая трубка волынки б) характерный звук басовой трубки волынки 
4) авиац. управляемый снаряд; беспилотный самолет 2. гл.

drone > truten/drojanij – трутень/дрожание (слав.)(редукция t/d, пропуск t; пропуск j), где «дрожание» - жужжание – бесцельное действие.

скутер (в английском словаре)
гл. 
1) шотл. выливать. пускать струю; течь, струиться 
2) шотл., амер. поскользнуться 
3) разг.; шутл. бежать, удирать; быстро двигать, перевозить Syn : make off, run away
(разговорное) стремительный бег - to make a * for shelter стрелой помчаться в укрытие поспешное бегство - to do a * удирать со всех ног (разговорное) бежать стремглав удирать, смываться (тж. * off, * away)
Первоначальное значение скутера – гоночное судно (БСЭ)
scoot разг., шутл. бежать, удирать (англ.) > strugnij – стружный (слав.)(пропуск tr, замена g/c) от сущ. струга – ладья (ст.-слав.)
Преобразования английских слов делается по методике поиска славянских слов в иностранных словах. http://www.tezan.ru/metod.htm